# Alterações perdidas no merge

Tags: git

Galera, fiz um merge equivocado e todas as novas alterações foram perdidas. E o commit anterior ao merge foi há dois meses atrás. A triste questão é: todas as alterações foram permanentemente perdidas?

**Log**

```
commit d52ac4b.....3ccf2a (refs/stash)
Merge: 92039fc xxxxxx
Author: @iann00 <xxxx@xxxx.com>
Date:   Tue Oct 1 09:51:45 2019 -0300

    On development: Uncommitted changes before Checkout at 01/10/2019 09:51

commit 9233eb3e....6ccb614
Author: @iann00 <xxxx@xxxx.com>
Date:   Tue Oct 1 09:51:45 2019 -0300

    index on development: 92039fc Merge branch 'development'

commit 92039fc499525926cf306d08d039c7eaac91ff0a (HEAD -> development, origin/master, master, dev)
Merge: d99fc98 5265edf
Author: @iann00 <xxxx@xxxx.com>
Date:   Tue Oct 1 08:20:56 2019 -0300

    Merge branch 'development'

commit e06c03d3....0818f508 (market)
Author: @iann00 <xxxx@xxxx.com>
Date:   Tue Oct 1 08:05:25 2019 -0300

    v1.1.6
```

Comment: Normalmente não tem como você fazer um merge de um repositório modificado sem antes de fazer um commit ou um stash. Qual foi, exatamente, o comando que você rodou pra fazer o merge?

Comment: Rapaz, o negócio tá ruim: eu não lembro. Com a cabeça quente eu fechei o console.

Comment: dá um git log e da uma olhada na sequencia dos commits, improvável ter perdido tudo

Comment: Rode `git log --all` pra ver o histórico de todos os branches. Talvez suas modificações estejam em algum. Se você está no Linux, verifique o histórico de comandos, provavelmente em `~/.bash_history`.

Comment: @giusti e @LucasMiranda, rodei `git log --all` como o giusti disse e o commit anterior da bobagem que fiz tá aqui!! Como posso recuperar agora?

Comment: Edite a sua pergunta atualizando a saída do `git log --all`. Apague informações sensíveis (email, textos de commit etc), mas deixe os nomes dos branches. Pelo menos o commit `92039fc49952592...` e os dados que você perdeu têm que estar visíveis.

Comment: @giusti, pronto

Comment: Ok, acho que dá pra resolver. Só pra confirmar, as alterações que você quer guardar são aquelas que estão no stash?

Comment: Se for isso, então acho que você só precisa dar um merge do `master` com esse *stash*. Mas eu não vou escrever uma resposta porque não estou muito confiante. Recomendo fazer uma cópia completa desse repositório (local) antes de tentar. Feito isso, experimente simplesmente rodar `git merge refs/stash` (**na cópia**). Se der tudo certo, faça de verdade no repositório original.

Comment: Eu estou começado agora com o Git, então não tenho tanta experiência. Eu rodei `git merge refs/stash`, mas obtive `Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.`. Resolvi não dar `commit`, e fazer um `git checkout <hash do último commit>` e os arquivos voltaram. Fiz correto?